# Getting integer input from the user at runtime in R

Tags: r

I want to get an input to an integer variable in my R code during runtime. I have mostly coded in C and want to know if there is some function like `scanf` in R that can be used to read input from the user?

Comment: Have you tried `readline`?

Comment: yes, I tried readline
Actually, the integer variable that I want to read controls the number of times a certain for loop runs in my code. But using readline, I got the error saying that tha variable (in my case,n) is NaN

Comment: `readline` returns a character string, so if you want a number you'll have to convert it via `as.numeric` or `as.integer`.

Comment: If you post your code, we can confirm that @HongOoi 's comment is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments above have said, you can use `readlines()` and then convert to an integer with `as.integer()`.

I'd also offer an alternative which is the `scan()` function.
The advantages of `scan()` are that it has `numeric` as the default class, so no need to convert to an integer.
Also by default it allows you to input unlimited values at a time and then return them in a single vector. This can be reduced to just a single value by using the `nmax=1` option.

```
> a=as.integer(readline())
123
> a
[1] 123


> b=scan()
1: 123
2: 456
3: 
Read 2 items
> b
[1] 123 456


> c=scan(,nmax=1)
1: 123
Read 1 item
> c
[1] 123
```