# How to ask the user for an integer at runtime, and recursively ask again if you didn't get one?

Tags: r, integer

I'm trying to write some code that does all of the following:

1. At run time, asks, with an actual question (e.g. "How many PCs do you have? ") the user to type in an integer.
2. Check if the user has given either an object of integer type or something that can be coerced in to that without error. This step must not require any sort of `grep` (e.g. that makes [this solution](http://www.rexamples.com/4/Reading%20user%20input) invalid).
3. Instead of giving any warning or errors if the input wasn't an integer, ask a new question that is repeated until they do give an integer (e.g. ask "Try again? " until an integer is given).
4. Outputs this integer.

The solutions to [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16933290/10319707) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36513162/10319707) appear to be to use either `scan` or `readlines`. I've ruled out `scan` because it likes to throw its own error messages, needs help from `print` to ask questions, and will ask for another input if given an invalid one even if you've told it to only try for one (e.g. `scan(n = 1,quiet = TRUE)` will ask for another input if you give it a bunch of letters). I've found that `readlines` is almost satisfactory, but because `readlines` treats its input as a string, I've been unable to write a`trycatch` block that satisfies requirement #3.

What are my options? It's looking like I've missed a simple solution.

Comment: You can capture the output from `readlines` and then use `type.convert(out, as.is = TRUE)` and then check the type on that

Comment: @akrun I'm struggling to see how that differs from checking the type of ```readlines``` directly.

Comment: Can you please check the solution below.  I am not sure if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could either use a recursive function or a `while` or `repeat` loop to check if the answer is numeric

```
f1 <- function(question){


  flag <- TRUE
    while(flag) {
    out <- readline(paste0(question, "\n"))
    out1 <- type.convert(out, as.is = TRUE)
    if(is.numeric(out1)) flag <- FALSE
    }


    out1
}


v1 <- f1('how many PCs')
how many PCs
not sure
how many PCs
you asked the wrong person
how many PCs
#2432
how many PCs
20


v1
#[1] 20
```

Or another option is to convert to integer with `as.integer`.  if there is any value that is not an integer/numeric, it would return NA.  Using `is.na` as a logical condition, we can change the `if` line in the above code

Comment: This looks about right, but I believe that this would accept numerics that are not integers.

Comment: @J.Mini I was thinking that i should use `is.integer` instead of `is.numeric`, but then if the user specifies 20.0 or 10.0, with type.convert it could be converted to numeric